# Python-LDAP Size limit exceeded

Tags: python, openldap, python-ldap

I see there is a way for me page the results in python and I found the following example code:
https://bitbucket.org/jaraco/python-ldap/src/f208b6338a28/Demo/paged_search_ext_s.py

When I copy this code and try to modify it to what I need it to do when running the code I get a "TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'cookie'"

I even reverted the code back to its default and get the same error. If someone could point me in the correct direction it would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your `python-ldap` module:

```
pip install python-ldap --upgrade
```

That class changed from this [commit](https://bitbucket.org/jaraco/python-ldap/commits/f1f028a0d77c#LLib/ldap/controls.pyF73) and [mentioned](https://bitbucket.org/jaraco/python-ldap/commits/f1f028a0d77c#LCHANGEST13):

> new class API in ldap.controls, not backwards-compatible!

Comment: For my distro I was up-to-date but had to update using pip / the download on their site. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is on this line:

```
req_ctrl = SimplePagedResultsControl(True,size=self.page_size,cookie='')
```

Find where that SimplePagedResultsControl class is defined and examine the parameter list for its constructor to get the correct constructor parameter list.

EDIT:

Looks like the constructor signature has been changed. Either upgrade as Omid Raha recommends or try the old method signature below if you are unable to upgrade for some reason.

```
paged_results_control = SimplePagedResultsControl(ldap.LDAP_CONTROL_PAGE_OID, True, (self.page_size, ''))
```

Comment: From python-ldaps documentation the parameter list is as follows: class ldap.controls.libldap.SimplePagedResultsControl(criticality=False, size=None, cookie=None)

Comment: Looks like your LDAP module is out of date compared to the docs as Omid Raha says. I have found the older constructor signature if you are unable to update your LDAP module for some reason. I have added it to my answer.

Comment: The old constructor didnt work for me either, I had to update the module as that worked on a test server.